# SFML getFullscreenModes

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

Have you ever run into issue where function in SFML 2 to get availiable modes returns you:

- availiableVideoModes    [3]({width=3131961357 height=3131961357 bitsPerPixel=3131961357 },{width=3131961357 height=3131961357 bitsPerPixel=3131961357 },{width=3131961357 height=3131961357 bitsPerPixel=3131961357 })  std::vector >

max int values in vector? Interesting is why 3? I tried quick debugging without luck so in parallel I thought to raise question here.

code:

```
    std::vector<sf::VideoMode> availiableVideoModes;
    availiableVideoModes = sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes();
```

interesting is that

```
    desktopVideoMode = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode();
```

returns correct value.

Comment: Which operating system? Have you tried to run your program on other computer? Can you show the code you used to print the video mode?

Comment: issue was in linking wrong libs.

Comment: Could you write this as your own answer and accept it, so people automatically know that this has been solved?

Comment: the answer is check what libs you are linking 64 or 32 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in libraries link, I have linked 32bits one instead of 64bits.